# Opencart | Как вывести внутренние данные товара, на страницу каталога?

Tags: php, opencart

У меня такая задача.
В магазине на Opencart, нужно выводить внутренние данные товара на страницу каталога, конкретнее это "Sales by amount" (пример: цена 200 руб, но за 400 получишь 3 штуки , что-то типо того).
Это хорошо отображается на странице товара, но мне нужно чтобы оно было видно в каталоге тоже, что есть такая акция.

Из страницы товара копирую код но не работает и понимаю почему (нужно как-то вызвать его из страницы товара наружу), но не могу решить это задачу.

Надеюсь понятно )

Comment: у страницы товара и страницы категории разные модели, соответственно наборы данных разные. смотрите как формируются страница товара и страница категории в контроллерах, и какие наборы данных отдают их модели.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Ваши данные, Вы хотите вывести, нужно определить в контроллере категории или там где Вы хотите их выводить через переменные, затем в шаблоне уже выводить эти переменные

```
$data['Sales_by_amoun'] = $result['Sales_by_amoun'];
{{ Sales_by_amoun }}
```